# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS WiFi-extender not working

Tags: wireless

My Ubuntu 20.04 cannot connect to the wifi extender. It can connect to the wifi.
I have tried these until now :

```
iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

enp2s0    no wireless extensions.

wlp3s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=off   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          
docker0   no wireless extensions.

bnep0     no wireless extensions.
```

and :

```
sudo lshw -C network
[sudo] password for amit: 
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: enp2s0
       version: 15
       serial: 0c:9d:92:2f:86:f2
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.13.0-52-generic firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:16 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:ef304000-ef304fff memory:ef300000-ef303fff
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 8265 / 8275
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlp3s0
       version: 78
       serial: b4:6b:fc:76:dc:2a
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.13.0-52-generic firmware=36.77d01142.0 8265-36.ucode latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:139 memory:ef200000-ef201fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 1
       logical name: bnep0
       serial: b4:6b:fc:76:dc:2e
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes ip=192.168.44.111 multicast=yes
```

I had Ubuntu 18.04 earlier, which crashed. Then after retrieving the data, I installed Ubuntu 20.04, after a few days this started happening. The WiFi-extender and repeater was working fine with Ubuntu 18.04, but not anymore.

On suggestion I ran the rfkill list command:

```
(base) amit@amit-X705UDR:~$ rfkill list
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Kindly advice me on solving the problem.
Regards to all.

Comment: It is totally unclear. What is the "wifi extender"?

Comment: wifi extender and repeater

Comment: Connected by USB?

Comment: I assume it acts like a wireless access point on its own, but is connected to the router's built-in AP via wifi, is that right? Something like [these](https://www.amazon.com/wifi-extender/s?k=wifi+extender)? Can any other devices connect to the wifi extender? Is it set up properly?

Comment: how did you try to connect to the extender? Can you describe exactly the steps you took and exactly how you know it "isn't working"?

Comment: I have edited the question, kindly have a look.

Comment: @Esther, yes you are right, it is the RE 200 from TP link wifi extender and Repeater. All the other devices connected with the RE200 work properly.

Comment: From Ubuntu's perspective, the repeater should just be like another Wifi network. Can you confirm that you tried to connect to the repeater the same way you would connect to any other wifi network? Can you give the exact steps you took to try to connect, and exactly how you know it isn't working? What happened when you tried to connect?

Comment: The wifi is shown as disabled on the computer so it won't connect using wifi.  If you want to connect using wifi, show results for `rfkill list`